# To read file and post it's whole content using SendKeys into text field using selenium library

Tags: java, sendkeys

I have used this code and passed it to send keys but it's not working !!
Give me solution to this problem .

```
  private static void readFile(String fileName)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    //read from first file
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(new File((fileName))));

                String lineContent = null;
                while( (lineContent = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] valArr = lineContent;                  
                }       

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally
            {
                if (br!= null)
                {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Then pass this string array to SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

You may get some error because of using string array functions without specifying the index value. Try with the below one,

```
private static void readFile(String fileName)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    //read from first file
    try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(new File((fileName))));

            String lineContent = null;
            String valArr[] = new String[10];
            int i =0;
            while( (lineContent = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                valArr [i] = lineContent;
                i++;                 
            } 

            for(int j=0; i>=j; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(valArr[j]);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    finally
        {
            if (br!= null)
            {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```